# How to check if a File has been chosen by JFileChooser?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, jfilechooser

I create a GUI in Netbeans with `JFileChooser` Button, a process `JButton`, and a status `JText`. What I want, if I press process Button without inputing a file with `Filechooser` there would be a warning status in Text that says you haven't input a File. Problem is, how to check it and code it in some if-else form? I tried it with `File == null` but there's no response. Here is some code of `FileChooser`.

```
int returnLatih = chFileLatih.showOpenDialog(this);
if (returnLatih == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    fileLatih = chFileLatih.getSelectedFile();
} else {}
```

Comment: I don't get your problem. The `else` case in your code is the case when no file is selected. Maybe you should add `fileLatih = null` in your `else` case.

Comment: `getSelectedFile()` *tells* you which file has been selected. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what exactly is your problem - however you could try something along this lines.

```
fileLatih = null;
int returnLatih = chFileLatih.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnLatih == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        fileLatih = chFileLatih.getSelectedFile();
    } else {
      System.out.println("File Chooser was cancelled");      
 }
if (fileLatih == null) {
   System.out.println("I got no file name!!");
}
```

I suppose that either you do not handle the else case, or your `fileLatih` keeps some old value and when you compare it with `null` - it isn't.